# MDL - How to remove underline from input

Tags: html, css

In my app I use Material Design Lite, but I want to get rid of the input's underline. I tried to use text-decoration: none, but it doesn't help at all.
Snipet:

```css
.form-label {
    padding: 8px 0 0 8px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
  }

  .form-input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 4px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield checkout_form">
     <label class="form-label" for="last-name">Last name</label>
     <input class="mdl-textfield__input form-input" type="text" placeholder="Musk">
  </div>
</body>
```

Feel free to use this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wv60b1ns/

Comment: it's a border ....

Comment: @TemaniAfif tried it earlier, border: none; is not working in this case

Comment: your code need to be placed after the CSS of material design

Comment: @TemaniAfif it is

Comment: it's not; https://jsfiddle.net/14uzjqv7/2/

Comment: @TemaniAfif oh, you're right. Thanks for help, mate!